# What is up with Shoooes.net (Ruby UI module)

Tags: ruby, user-interface

I have been looking at ways to program a UI in ruby here, on SO, and on Google. Everyone keeps saying that Shoooes is the way to go. However every link to the site and the site of the person behind it has been failing for at least a week.

So what's the deal with that, where else can I go for information on Shoooes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this mirror - http://github.com/whymirror/shoes/downloads

The library was written by Why - a mystical and legendary character in Ruby mythology. One day he packed his stuff and just left - his online presence just a memory in the minds of his fans.
http://ejohn.org/blog/eulogy-to-_why/

Some of his fans have salvaged some of his work on github. For shoes, the canonical reference is 'Nobody knows Shoes' - nks.pdf on the link above. I admire the guy for his work.

Answer (score 2):

The creator of Shoes disappeared. Read http://www.rubyinside.com/why-the-lucky-stiff-is-missing-2278.html

Check out http://github.com/whymirror/shoes for Shoes info.